# Modifying values of an array with a threshold value, without using if statements. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, if-statement

I'm thinking of a way to solve this problem in a more efficient way.

I have a large array of integers

```
[170,158,147,139,134,132,133,136,141,.....]
```

I have a calculated threshold values of `132` & `137`

What I want to do is modify any numbers in my array that are < `132` to be set to some other value, say `100`. And any number in my array > `137` to be set to a different value, `150`.

It would be easy to write a fuinction

```
for (i < array.length)
    if(array[i] < 132)
        array[i] = 100;
    if(array[i] > 137)
        array[i] = 150
```

But for the size of my array(20k+), having this many ifs would take a very long time.

I need to retain the order of the array, so sorting wont work for this.

Maybe some type of bitwise operation could work on this.

Comment: Are you sure the `if`s are your bottleneck? Have you tried it?

Comment: Computationally speaking, I don't really think there's something way better than that.

Comment: Pretty sure a `for` loop with `if` statements like you described is the most time-efficient way to map an array like that.

Comment: I just ran this in node with a 30K-item array of random integers. The loop took 1.6ms on my laptop. 300k items took about 3ms. This seems like a case of premature optimization (aka the root of all evil).

Comment: this runs at O(N). There really isn't a more effluence way to do this.

Comment: @Mark_M if you simply want to limit what array[I] can be: `myArray[i] = constrain(myArray[i], 132, 137);`

Comment: @brc where is `constrain()` defined?

Comment: @Mark_M Oops. Its defined in the p5 lib: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/constrain

Comment: @Mark_M I did not mean to tag you in my `constrain()` comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it could be faster;

```
var given=[170,158,147,139,134,132,133,136,141,.....];
var result=given.map(x=> x<132 ? 100 : (x>137 ? 150 : x));
```

Comment: You should compare this with the code in the OP. On my system it runs about 10 times slower than a plain `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah this is fore sure requires more computation than the code in the OP

Comment: Using teranary is the same thing as using if statements, and the map function will be much slower than the for loop.

Comment: I'd just posted the same -- shocking!  This should be parallelizable and faster for it. Probably depends on the JS engine at that point.

Comment: Look into `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to see computing times.

Comment: @StephenP you're right but I don't think the question requires (or could benefit from) concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on with your for loop but if you use a regular for loop (i.e. `for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {}` it's much faster than one using `for (i in array) {}`. Take a look at how much faster it is using an array with a length of 1,000,000 :

```js
var bigData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  bigData[i] = i;
}

console.time('TEST1');
for (i=0; i < bigData.length; i++) {
    if(bigData[i] < 132)
        bigData[i] = 100;
    if(i > 137)
        bigData[i] = 150
}
console.timeEnd('TEST1');

console.time('TEST2');
for (i in bigData) {
    if(i < 132)
        i = 100;
    if(i > 137)
        i = 150
}
console.timeEnd('TEST2');
```